# Алгоритм бронирования длинного стола по частям

Tags: алгоритм

Бронирование мест в кабаке. Есть длинные столы, состоящие из N маленьких. За каждым маленьким можно усадить по 2 человека, и только за крайними — по 3 (два по бокам и один во главе стола, выходит):

```
  x  x  x  x
x[ ][ ][ ][ ]x
  x  x  x  x
  1  2  3  4
```

Есть вариант длинных столов, когда во главе стола только с одной из сторон есть место.

Посетители выбирают стол и указывают, сколько человек будет.

Искомый алгоритм бронирования должен оптимально выбирать места для K человек за выбранным ими столом. Напр. если пришло 3 человека и стол пока пустой — пусть им отойдёт крайний столик, понятно. Пришло 2 - им с другого конца край.

```
  o   x  x   o
o[-] [ ][ ] [-]x
  o   x  x   o
  1   2  3   4
```

Пересаживать нежелательно - купили - получили письмо с билетом на двоих за столик 21(3) напр. Может, лучше было двоим отпилить 3-й столик, т.к. *вероятнее*, что кому-то ещё понадобится сразу 3 места? Что говорит теорвер?

Вопроса ещё два:

1. известен ли вам "классический" алгоритм для такой задачи постепенного распила?
2. как бы лучше в коде описать такие длинные столы и их текущую заполненность? Язык непринципиален, но сейчас пишу это на JS, длинный стол - объект (там ещё его отрисовка в SVG). От сервера про длинный стол приходит JSON с номерами под-столов `: )` для каждой брони: `[{"n":4,"desks":[1,2]},{"n":3,"desks":[4]},]`

Ощущение, что изобретаю велосипед, не даёт покоя. Нужен свежий взгляд!

Comment: > Пришло 2 - им с другого конца край.

Непонятно, почему это оптимально. Не лучше ли посадить их за второй столик слева, чтобы если придут ещё 5 человек, им нашлось место?

Comment: Это я предположил из логики, по которой занимают писсуары - стараясь макс. дистанцироваться от соседей : ) Для 2 с другого конца на самом деле имеет смысл только для случая "с одним тамадой" - когда только с одной стороны во главе кто-то сидит, и уже нечет как раз занят.

Выбор между комфортом и оптимальным заполнением. Ещё правило такое: Если придёт три, а есть только 2x2 столика, им придётся выкупить 4 места.

Comment: Тогда не совсем понятно целевая функция. Я правильно понимаю алгоритм: (1) группа должна сидеть вместе, (2) если возможно, должно быть свободное место между новичками и теми, кто уже за столом, (3) дано вероятностное распределение количества людей в группе, (4) найти алгоритм, максимизирующий матожидание среднего количества людей за столиком.

Comment: Правильно. Только данные по (3) начнут собираться с нуля, как запустим эту систему. Это блюзовый клуб, туда далеко не всегда ходят парами за ручку.

Comment: Угу, понял. Надо подумать, а вообще, задача для математиков, а не программистов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Очень не уверен в своем варианте и написал бы в коменте, да не влазит зараза )) Ну, да ладно, рискнем )*

Внизу ссылка на пример, но так как там полный *овнокод, то опишу смысл тут. Секции стола и посадочные места находяться в многомерном массиве, точнее объекте:

```
var allTables = {
    0:{
        t1:[0,0,0],
        t2:[0,0],
        t3:[0,0],
        t4:['reserv1','reserv1'],
        t5:[0,0,0]
    },
    1:{
        t1:['reserv2','reserv2','reserv2'],
        t2:[0,0],
        t3:[0,0],
        t4:[0,0],
        t5:[0,0,0]
    },
    2:{
        t1:[0,0,0],
        t2:[0,0],
        t3:[0,0],
        t4:[0,0],
        t5:[0,0,0]
    }
};
```

Нулевые значения - это пустые места. Значениями забронированных мест, могут быть номера заказов или же просто какое-то значение != 0 на своё усмотрение. Получаем количество мест, которое надо забронировать (для примера берем **4**). Пробегаемся по столам, в каждом находим подряд идущие пустые места. К примеру, на первом столе - это будет 7 и 3 места. В том же цикле, находим полностю пустые секции и их кол-во мест. Опять же, на первом столе - получаем такой массив [3,2,2,0,3]. *Попралюсь: не массивы, а объекты*. Далее сравниваем нужное кол-во мест бронирования с первым объектом. Если это количество 7 или 3, то возвращаем соответствующий ключ. Так как мы условились, что мест 4, то идем дальше. Ищем совпадение во втором объекте. Если бы нам надо было забронировать 2 или 3 места, то при совпадении, мы так же вернули бы соответствующий ключ, но у нас 4 и мы переходим к простому перебору, используя второй объект (*[3,2,2,0,3]*). Ищем ближайшие пустые секции, количество мест которых, в сумме даст нам нужное, т.е. 4. В нашем случае, подходят вторая и третяя секции: **t2,t3**. Вычислив их, мы передаем массив ключей этих секций. Дальше дело техники. В объектах, изменяем нулевые значения на номер заказа. Если надо, то выводим на экран.

Теперь буквально пару слов, о том, если на текущем столе не найдено приличного варианта. К примеру, число мест **6**. В этом случае, вместо ключей, мы получаем "undefined" и рекурсивно отправляем в вышеуказанный процесс индекс "второго стола". Там, для 6-ти мест, найдется вариантик из 2-ой, 3-й и 4-ой секций. Если мест надо 12, то естественно, что остановимся на "третьем столе".

Собственно, вот мой [*овнопример в действии](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/3RzB2/3/). Сказать, что он не доработан - это значит ничего не сказать, но на моих часах 5 утра и нет сил бороться. )) Так или иначе, надеюсь, что хоть чем-то помог.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный ответ! Усложнили сверх задачи, или я нечётко описал. Столы одномерные: `####` и по одному человеку за одним сидеть точно не может: за под-столик сажают min 2 (хочет прийти 1 - надо купить 2 билета), или опционально 3 за крайний. Поэтому можно описывать занятость длинного стола как массив из 0,2, или 3: `[3,0,0,2]`. Тогда максимум, который можно за него усадить это `(число 0-подряд)*2` + число вошедших туда крайних нулей. Или в отдельном массиве держать максимумы мест: `[3,2,2,2]` для стола, у которого во главе можно посадить только с одной из сторон.

Comment: А для svg-отрисовки граница нулевого и ненулевого значения занятости станет индикатором "разрыва" стола в этом месте.

Спасибо, помогли мне «въехать» в задачу! Сделаю так, покажу, что выходит!